# c# BitmapImage to Bitmap converting out of memory error

Tags: c#, bitmap, stream, converters, bitmapimage

I'm currently trying to convert a large image from BitmapImage -> Bitmap.  On smaller files the conversion works great, the issue stems from trying to convert an image that is <5MB. After doing some reading I think I should be using some sort of buffer to populate the bitmap but not sure.  Any point in the right direction would be helpful.  Thanks!

Error message thrown:

```
'outStream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

/// <summary>
/// Convert a BitmapImage found in a Image.Source to a Bitmap
/// </summary>
/// <param name="bitmapImage"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static Bitmap BitmapImageToBitmap(BitmapImage bitmapImage)
{
    // Opens a stream to be used for the image conversion
    using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // Grabs the encoder object to be used as a converter
        BitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();

        // Adds the bitmap as a frame of the encoder (this adds the image as a 'page' for the bitmap image)
        BitmapFrame frame = BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapImage);
        encoder.Frames.Add(frame);

        // Saves the current set of frames (single page for now) to the stream
        encoder.Save(outStream);
        encoder.Frames.Clear();
        encoder = null;
        frame = null;
        // Initialize a new Bitmap image using the stream
        return new Bitmap(outStream);         <--- This is where the error is thrown
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to keep the stream ( `outStream` ) alive and open. So don't create it with the `using` statement. `var` it. Read the [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#system-drawing-bitmap-ctor(system-io-stream)) section of the Bitmap(Stream) overload. The caller should dispose of the returned bitmap to clean up.

Comment: @dr.null so why does it work for smaller files?

Comment: The GC work is not predictable. You can't tell when it performs a clean up task. Maybe small files + enough memory = not critical point to get involved and take an action to collect and free resources. With your code as is, try to call `GC.Collect();` in the caller side after you get the bitmap to see what happens regardless the file size.

Comment: Forgot to mention, a 5MB size on desk does not mean 5MB in memory. According to the image type, compression level and maybe other factors, it could be 5MB x 10 in memory.